# .Net IBM MQ Error "MQRCCF_CFIN_PARM_ID_ERROR" 3014

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

When I try to get the queue names from a queue manager, I am getting this error which I couldn't understand why

```
PCFMessage reqeuestMessage = new PCFMessage(MQC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q);
reqeuestMessage.AddParameter(MQC.MQIA_Q_TYPE, MQC.MQQT_LOCAL);
PCFMessage[] pcfResponse = messageAgent.Send(reqeuestMessage);
```

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where's the queue name parameter?

```
PCFMessage reqeuestMessage = new PCFMessage(MQC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q);
reqeuestMessage.AddParameter(MQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, "*");
reqeuestMessage.AddParameter(MQC.MQIA_Q_TYPE, MQC.MQQT_LOCAL);
reqeuestMessage.AddParameter(MQCFC.MQIACF_Q_ATTRS,
                             new int [] { MQC.MQCA_Q_NAME,
                                          MQC.MQIA_Q_TYPE,
                                          MQC.MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH,
                                          MQC.MQIA_OPEN_INPUT_COUNT,
                                          MQC.MQIA_OPEN_OUTPUT_COUNT });
PCFMessage[] pcfResponse = messageAgent.Send(reqeuestMessage);
```

You need to list what you are requesting AND what you want back from the request.

There are not many C# .NET PCF examples but there are hundreds or thousands of Java PCF examples.  Just model your C# .NET code after the Java PCF code.

Answer (score 2):

IBM has stated that the PCF support that is included in the MQ Classes for .NET  not documented or maintained.  For reference look at Page 16 of the MQ Technical Conference v2.0.1.5 presentation "[PCF Programming](http://www.mqtechconference.com/sessions_v2015/MQ_PCF.pdf)" by Mark Taylor of IBM MQ Development:

> - Some use .Net classes: **that interface is not *documented* or *maintained***
>
>   - An historic accident
>   - Missing newer function such as z/OS and byte string support

---

I verified that the PCF interface for the MQ classes for .NET is still not documented in the IBM MQ Knowledge center, but of interest is that they have take a few APARs in this area recently and resolved them:

- [IT02687: DOTNET APPLICATION SENDING PCF MESSAGES GET NO RESPONSE WHEN REQUESTS ARE SENT TO A Z/OS QUEUE MANAGER](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT02687) - August 2014 - Fixed in 7.5.0.5
- [IT12297: THE MQ .NET CLASSES FAIL TO INITIALIZE AN MQCFSL STRUCTURE WHEN PROCESSING A PCF RESPONSE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT12297) - May 2016 - Fixed in 7.5.0.7/8.0.0.5

---

Microsoft Developer All About Interop blog post "[PCF with IBM’s MQ Classes for .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnetinterop/2005/12/02/pcf-with-ibms-mq-classes-for-net/)" has some examples, you probably need to use `MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_NAMES` instead of `MQC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q`.  From the blog:

```
PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent(c.MQ_QueueManager);
PCFMessage request= new PCFMessage(CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_NAMES);
request.AddParameter (MQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, queuename);
request.AddParameter (MQC.MQIA_Q_TYPE, MQC.MQQT_LOCAL);
PCFMessage[] responses = agent.Send(request);
```

---

Another example is in @Sashi's answer to Stack Overflow question "[MQ Statistics Monitoring from C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178088/mq-statistics-monitoring-from-c-net/16183965#16183965)".